# How to Set Up folder Based Virtual Hosting (Vhosts) With Apache Web Server on ubuntu like /localhost/site1 localhost/site2

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, codeigniter

I am trying to configure virtual hosts with multiple sites with codeigniter based on folders on ubuntu 18 with Apache2. By this what I mean is site1 is to be accessed by using url http://localhost/site1 and site2 is to be accessed by using url http://localhost/site2 and site3 is to be accessed by using url http://localhost/site3 and so on. Content to be served are in folders under /var/www/site1 and /var/www/site2 etc. I can't use name based virtual hosts because the users will be using it over the network not in the local machine.

So I updated default config file on ubuntu like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    Alias /site1 /var/www/site1/html
    <Directory /var/www/site1/html>
            Options +MultiViews -Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
  </Directory>

    
           Alias /site2 /var/www/site2/html
    <Directory /var/www/site2/html>
            Options +MultiViews -Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

  Alias /site3 /var/www/site3/html
    <Directory /var/www/site3/html>
            Options +MultiViews -Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
  </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Folder structure is like below
/var/www/site1/html
/var/www/site2/html
/var/www/site3/html
etc.

I am able to access site1 normally without any issue. But for site2 and site3 I am getting 500 internal server error with message " Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. " in the logs. When enabled debug mode following messages were in the log.

```
: r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895466 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895478 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895490 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895501 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895512 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895523 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895534 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895562 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895573 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/html/index.php/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
[Mon Feb 01 12:07:57.895583 2021] [core:debug] [pid 8335] core.c(3840): [client 192.186.1.3:57079] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site2/master/get_announcements, referer: http://192.186.1.4/site2/
```

If it helps following is the .htaccess in the /var/www/site2 folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This same .htaccess is present in all the three directories. But it works only for first one for other 2 it gives error as mentioned above.

Please help me fix this.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: try adding

```
RewriteBase /site2
```

in the .htaccess for site2. And similarly for /site1 and /site3.

From the error log, the problem is clearly in the RewriteRule, which is creating an infinite loop of adding `/html/index.php` to the front of the URL.

The problem is in this condition:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The RewriteCond is trying to exclude URLs that already start with `index.php`, `public`, and so on. In a .htaccess file, that doesn't work unless you tell Apache to remove the leading part of the URL with `RewriteBase`, as above. See the docs for [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), and also the sections "What is matched?" and "Per-directory Rewrites" in the docs for [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), although warning, those sections are really hard to understand.

I guess the reason the rule works for /site1 but not the others is that /site1 includes an index.php file, so the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` fails and the RewriteRule isn't triggered.

By the way you don't need a `<VirtualHost>` here, since you're serving all 3 of these directories from the same hostname (http://localhost).